# Viewing complete computed Apache httpd configuration?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, configuration

Is there a command / tool to generate the computed configuration that Apache httpd is using? I know I can manually go through the httpd.conf and other configuration files, but is there a standard tool to generate a configuration of all included files and sections that apply, for convenience?

Thanks,

James

**Edit:** I should also have mentioned I'm also using a Windows x-64 version of Apache, from a pre-built binary.

Comment: +1 for great question! I've been administering Apache for more than ten years and only now I realized I have always glimpsed through configuration files instead of the kind of view you are asking for. It sure would be nice to have a view similar to phpinfo() in PHP. :-)

Comment: @Janne thanks :) I've used Maven before on Java projects as a build tool, which uses various 'POM' XML files for configuration (in various folders) and has a way to do such a thing - view all combined files as one generated POM. I think such a tool is invaluable when trying to sort out configuration

Answer (score 5):

There is an Apache module available which shows a detailled page with various settings and the active configuration.

[`mod_info`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html) is disabled by default and must be enabled with `./configure --enable-info` when building Apache. On Debian and Ubuntu, this module and its configuration can be enabled using `sudo a2enmod info`.

Put the next lines in your configuration file (httpd.conf) (not necessary when using `a2enmod`):

```
<Location /server-info>
    SetHandler server-info
</Location>
```

After restarting the server, the configuration file is available at http://example.com/server-info?config (replace `example.com` with your server address)

Note that this information is quite sensitive, you might want to restrict access as in:

```
<Location /server-info>
  SetHandler server-info
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from yourcompany.com
</Location>
```

For more information, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I guess it is one way of doing it, but I'm looking for a more offline solution - especially with the access control concerns. I think I'd also suggest using some random path instead of `/server-info` just in case :)

Comment: `/server-info` is the default path, hence I'm using it to avoid confusion. Security-wise, you would indeed use a different path with strict access control and disable it after you're done. You could set up Basic/Digest authentication, restrict access to localhost and use `curl` combined with `html2text` to get the data in a script.

Answer (score 0):

With `mod_info` enabled:

```
apache2ctl -DDUMP_CONFIG|grep -vE "^[ ]*#[ ]*"
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51585410/936512

OR try: https://serverfault.com/a/743425/166429 (I have not tried this myself)