# Show content of loaded sites-available in apache2 under ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache2

I accidentally deleted a .conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available.

Is there a way to retrieve the content of it?
When I type `a2query -s`, I see that the deleted .conf is still loaded, since I did not restart apache2 yet. I want to see the content of it.

Comment: Maybe you can try this https://serverfault.com/questions/733961/is-there-a-command-to-get-apache-to-display-its-running-config-from-memory ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I get this error in a loop: `[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
^C0x00007fcd3194ecd7 in __GI___select (nfds=0, readfds=0x0, writefds=0x0, exceptfds=0x0, timeout=0x7ffdb9e0fdd0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/select.c:41
41      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/select.c: No such file or directory.
[Inferior 1 (process 7720) detached]` 7720 is the PID of apache2.